# Testing structures of vc++ using google test

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, googletest

I have a structure like

```
    struct sList{
       bool y.....
       int x......
       short int.... 
    sList(){
       x=0, y =true;......};
    };
```

Class A , calculation method.

```
    A::sList A::calcualtion(int i){
       sList result;
       result.x=10;
       .............
       .............
       .............
       return result; }
```

for this i will be writting a Google test like i will fill my structure with the values. And my test structure and this A class returning structure is equal or not i want test. how to test this using Google test or GMock. i using vc++ MFC Dialog box application.

Can i do like this????

```
     ASSERT_EQ(List , Result); //both are structures like A::sList List & A->calculation(i);
```

Comment: did you try it? what was the outcome?

Comment: see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQ<T1,T2>(const char *,const char *,const T1 &,const T2 &)' being compiled

Comment: see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::EqHelper<lhs_is_null_literal>::Compare<A::sList,A::sResult>(const char *,const char *,const T1 &,const T2 &)' being compiled
1>  with

Comment: I think this not correct way total structure comparison we cant do in c++. but we can test those member variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by writing operator overloading "==" in structure.

```
     struct PT 
       {   
        double x, y;  
        PT() {}  
        PT(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}  
        PT(const PT &p) : x(p.x), y(p.y)    {}  
        PT operator + (const PT &p)  const { return PT(x+p.x, y+p.y); }  
        PT operator == (const PT &p)  const { return PT(x==p.x, y==p.y); }  
        PT operator * (double c)     const { return PT(x*c,   y*c  ); }  
        PT operator / (double c)     const { return PT(x/c,   y/c  ); }  
       };
```